# Spellcheck for German

Tags: ms-word

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010, and I'm wondering whether it's possible to turn on spellchecking for German. The spellcheck works fine for English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the ability to check German spelling if you purchase and install a German Single Language Pack for Office . See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/suites  for more information and a link to purchase. You cannot legally download Office language packs from anywhere.